# Charging Indicator for Battery (Battery Monitor)

Tags: indicator, batterylevel

We see in all today electronic devices like mobile a Visual battery charging indicator,that a graphical Container composed of bars that increases one by one when the battery is charged for long, and decreases one by one when the mobile is used for long time. 
I see the same thing laptop in every GUI operating system like windows and Linux.
I am not sure whether i am posting in the right place, because this requires a **System Programmer** and **Electrical Engineer**.
A Visual view of my Question is here:

> http://gickr.com/results4/anim_eaccb534-1b58-ec74-697d-cd082c367a25.gif

I am thinking from long long ago , under what logic this works?
How the Program is managed to Monitor the battery.
I made a simple logic based on Amps-hour, that how much time the bar should increase when the battery is in charging mode.??? But that does not work perfectly for me.
Also i read a battery indicator **Android application** source code of my fried, but the function he used were System Calls based on Andriod Kernel (Linux Kernel).

I need the thing from the scratch....
I need this logic to know............. Because i am working on an Operating system kernel project, which later on will need battery charging monitor.

But the thing i will implement right now is to show just percentage on the Console Screen. 
Please give me an idea how i can do it.... Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating amps over time is not a reliable way to code a battery meter. Use voltage instead.

1. Refer to the battery's datasheet for a graph of (approximate) voltage vs. charge level.
2. Obtain an analog input to your CPU. If it's a microcontroller with a built-in ADC, then hopefully that's sufficient.
3. Plug a reference voltage (e.g. a zener diode) into the analog input. As the power supply voltage decreases, the reference will appear to increase because the ADC only measures voltage proportionally. The CPU may include a built-in reference voltage generator that you can mux to the ADC, or the ADC might always measure relative to a fixed reference instead of rail-to-rail. Consult the ADC manual (or ADC section of micro controller manual) for details.
4. Ensure that the ADC provides sufficient accuracy.
5. Sample the battery level and run a simple low-pass filter to eliminate noise, like `displayed_level = (displayed_level * 0.95) + (measured_level * 0.05)`. Run that through an approximate function mapping the apparent reference voltage to the charge level.
6. Display the charge level.